Elasticsearch java rest client error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
I have tried way too many Elasticsearch/Opensearch java rest client versions but running into issues with all of them.
Opensearch - 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.4
Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair

Elasticsearch Rest high level client - 7.10.2, 7.11.2, 7.12.0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.client.ml.dataframe.OutlierDetection

Elasticsearch Rest high level client - 7.15.0, 7.17.4
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.client.analytics.InferencePipelineAggregationBuilder

Elasticsearch Rest high level client - 7.13.2
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair

Pretty standard way of loading the dependency
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>

I'm writing to an opensearch cluster via a spark streaming application. What could be the issue?

This normally happens if you have incompatible versions of dependencies or transitive dependencies.

@MarkRotteveel how do i identify whats interfering with elasticsearch depedencies. I tried using dependency analyzer of intelliJ but it doesn't get me answers..

Use mvn dependency:tree and cross-reference the actual dependency versions expected by Elasticsearch with those that are actually pulled in. If they are different (especially major versions), then that could be the cause, then find out what is causing a different version to be pulled in: your own version configuration, or other dependencies (including BOMs) you use.
